# Can't change the cursor (from inside OnSetCursor)

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm trying to change the cursor inside my `CStatic`-derived class by handling `OnSetCursor`

```
class CMyStatic : public CStatic
{
    // ....
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyStatic, CStatic)
    ON_WM_SETCURSOR()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CMyStatic::OnSetCursor(CWnd* pWnd, UINT nHitTest, UINT message) 
{
    TRACE(_T("OnSetCursor\n"));
    SetCursor(AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_CROSS));
    return TRUE;
}
```

`OnSetCursor` gets called every time I move the mouse, but the cursor isn't changed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use ::SetCursor. Or you can call SetCursor once elsewhere and don't capture WM_SETCURSOR, and the cursor will be set automatically.

The CWnd::SetCursor you used is for setting a cursor for a window, and that cursor will be used if you don't override OnSetCursor. That is, the default behavior of OnSetCursor is calling ::SetCursor with the cursor one set by calling CWnd::SetCursor.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need (or want) to use `MAKEINTRESOURCE` in this case, so change:

```
SetCursor(AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CROSS)));
```

To:

```
SetCursor(AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_CROSS));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I removed MAKEINTRESOURCE. But it's still not working, the cursor isn't changed.

Comment: @satuon: At a guess the problem must be related to doing it in a subclassed control then -- I just tested in a normal view, and it works fine there.

Comment: Thanks, I just changed the base class to CWnd and it's all working now. Could you edit your answer so I can select it?

Answer (score 1):

```
m_hHandCursor = LoadCursor(NULL ,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_HAND));
```

Make m_hHandCursor as member variable and initialize using win32 API LoadCursor in OnInitDialog....Then OnSetCursor() event set this cursor always using SetCursor API....So your application will always get system defined HAND cursor

Comment: Please expand your answer to include explanation.